# Query in MongoDB by field in array, based on another field of this array

Tags: arrays, mongodb

So, I'm using mongo db 2.6. The structure of my collection is like:

```
{
  _id: '1', 
  items: [
    {index: '1', value: 'pretty'},
    {index: '1-section', value: 'good'},
    {index: '2', value: 'ugly'},
    {index: '2-section', value: 'bad'},
  ]
},
{
  _id: '2',
  items: [
    {index: '1', value: 'pretty'},
    {index: '1-section', value: 'good'},
    {index: '2', value: 'beautifull'},
  ]
}
```

As you can see, `items` is holding an array of objects, and each object has a corresponding "section" object.

My goal is to find documents where the item hasn't the corresponding object. Output sample:

```
{
  _id: '2',
  items: [
    {index: '1', value: 'pretty'},
    {index: '1-section', value: 'good'},
    {index: '2', value: 'beautifull'},
  ]
}
```

Naming pattern is {index}-section.
I use to achieve this via a javascript script but `collection` is very large and it doesn't work as fast as I need.

Will be very grateful for help.

Comment: I have no idea what you are saying, in-understandable. Can you provide the output of what you want?

Comment: Added output sample

Comment: Your naming pattern here is the problem. Instead your should identify the "section" data as a property on the related array item itself. Then you can easily and efficiently tell if the data is missing or not. Right now, all you really have available is scanning each document via [`$where`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/) in order to "split" the filtered arrays and compare them to find the missing entry. That may be better than processing the cursor results in client code like you are likely doing now, but it's still not a great solution.